# Query Sharepoint List

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, sharepoint-2013, office365

I have got a Office365 site that has a Sharepoint list that I want to query.

I want to query it from an Android app written in Xamarin.Android. I currently have a small .NET console app that successfully reads all the items from the list using the client object model.

I tried adding the console app logic to an xamarin business project, but referencing `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`, results in a build error:
`The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.
Also it cannot find `System.Security.SecureString` even considering that I'm targeting .NET 4.0.

My project has only 3 referenced dlls:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
.NET Portable 4.0 Subset
```

Why aren't these namespaces and classes recognized?

Comment: I guess that cause of the problem could be that xamarin has some sort of light weight version of .net which does not have all dlls which are required by sharepoint client api. You can always use REST api to query data on sharepoint site.

Comment: You can't just use any arbitrary .NET dll with Xamarin.  If you want to interact with SP, I would try using Sharepoint web services.

Comment: note: MonoTouch (now known as Xamarin.iOS) is for iOS, not Android.

Comment: I might have an alternative solution, which does not require to reference Sharepoint libraries. Have you thought about using OData?

Comment: If you are using a PCL project, `System.Security.SecureString` is definitely not in there.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes when I got stuck with this I tried OData and Rest services. I can access my list in a browser when authenticated. but didn't manage to authenticate while in the app (a lot of oauth pain). And that's when I started having second thoughts. Oh well...back to Rest api.

Comment: Look at the RestSharp component, it will help minimize the oAuth pain - https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp

Comment: If Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets replies with his answer I'll be happy to accept it.